# histgram by group and use seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/subhadipml/California-Housing-Price-Prediction/master/housing.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url)
df
x1 = df[df['ocean_proximity'] == "NEAR BAY"]
x2 = df[df['ocean_proximity'] == "<1H OCEAN"]

#Make a histogram of x1 with nice titles, axes labels and colored blue.

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kwargs = dict(hist_kws={'alpha':.6},kde_kws={'linewidth':2})
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7),dpi=80)
sns.distplot(x1, color='blue',label='NEAR_BAY',**kwargs)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-4b17a157e7b5> in <module>()
      1 #make the histogram
----> 2 sns.distplot(x1, color='blue',label='NEAR_BAY',**kwargs)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'NEAR BAY'
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: What do you want to plot?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick a column to plot. E.g.:

```
sns.distplot(x1["median_house_value"], color='blue',label='NEAR_BAY')
```

[image]